# Need a Web part to display user profile of selected user in SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: web-part, data-view-web-part, sharepoint-foundation

I am searching for a Data View web part which can display user profile of selected user in SharePoint foundation 2010. There will be one web part which will contain list of users and another one should display user profile of selected user.

Comment: what properties are you after though e.g username,email etc...Be specific.Maybe SP Designer would do.

Comment: users Photo,username,hobby,email,about his professional experiences and many more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with SharePoint designer. You need Data View web part with [UserProfileService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa980957%28v=office.12%29.aspx) webservice (http:///_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx) as datasource.

There is step-by-step tutorial at:

- [Current User’s Profile Properties…for lazy people](http://olenicksharepoint.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/current-users-profile-properties-for-lazy-people/)

This is good starting point and here you have few links that I think can help you some more:

- [Create data views in SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-data-views-in-sharepoint-designer-HA101631628.aspx#_Toc257804858)
- [Add a SOAP service as a data source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-soap-service-as-a-data-source-HA010355752.aspx#_Toc267299770)
- [Connect two Data Views](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/connect-two-data-views-HA010169133.aspx)

Comment: Vedran's answer should do

Comment: Thanks Vedran for your reply.Now I am installing SharePoint designer to follow the steps you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If don’t know if this is much of a help, but we have a field that can pull any AD or user profile  property into list field.
http://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=UserProperty